# A question about the proof of the open mapping theorem (2.11) in Walter Rudin's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, open-map

Can refer to page 65-66 of [this pdf](https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/functional-analysis-_-rudin-2th.pdf).

I actually have two questions about the proof. The first is, in proving the first part of (2), why $\overline{\Lambda (V_2)}$ contains a neighborhood of $0$? I think it only proves $\overline{\Lambda (V_2)}$ has a nonempty interior. It is not quite obvious to me why this interior must contain $0$.

My second question is, in proving the second part of (2), why $y_{m+1} \to 0$? I don't quite see how this can be inferred from the continuity of $\Lambda$.

Comment: Note that it proves that $\overline{\Lambda(V_2)}$ has a non-empty interior.  It follows from this that $\overline{\Lambda(V_1)}$ contains a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: I was wandering why $V_2$ was used instead of $V_1$ in this exact fragment of the proof and why the minus signs were there. This question helped me find out what I was missing, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question: For any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $V_r=\{x\in X: d(x,0)<2^{-k}r\}$, where $r>0$ is  fixed.

$\overline{\Lambda(V_2)}$ has nonempty interior. Denote it by $W$. Let $x,y\in V_2$. Then
$$d(x-y),0)=d(x,y)\leq d(x,0)+d(0,y)<2^{-2}r +2^{-2}r=2^{-1}r$$
That is $V_2-V_2\subset V_1$; hence
$$0\in W-W\subset \overline{\Lambda(V_2)}-\overline{\Lambda(V_2)}\subset\overline{\Lambda(V_2)-\Lambda(V_2)}\subset\overline{\Lambda(V_1)}$$
$W-W$ is open neighborhood of $0$, and contained in $\overline{\Lambda(V_1)}$.
(The same argument works for $V_k$ ($k>2$) in place of $k=2$).

---

For your second question: notice that $y_n\in\overline{\Lambda(V_n)}$ for all $n$. Let $U$ be any neighborhood of $0$ in $Y$ and $G$ be symmetric open neighborhood of $0$ such that $G+G\subset U$. Choose $z_n\in V_n$ such that
$y_n-\Lambda z_n\in G$. Clearly $z_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ in $X$ since  $d(z_n,0)<2^{-n}r\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. The continuity of $\Lambda$ implies that for some $N$, $n\geq N$ implies that $\Lambda z_n\in G$. Putting things together, for $n\geq N$,
$$y_n=\big(y_n-\Lambda z_n\big) +\Lambda z_n\in G+G\subset U$$
This means that $y_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ in $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd question, I think "$y_n \rightarrow 0$" can be get directly from the precondition given by "Assume $n\ge 1$ and $y_n$ has been chosen in $\overline{\Lambda(V_n)}$", even without considering its follow-up construction steps of $x_n$.

1. $y_n \in \overline{\Lambda(V_n)}\Rightarrow y_n \rightarrow 0$.

Since Y is a T.V.S, for any neighborhood U of 0 in Y, we have a neighborhood W of 0 in Y,s.t. $\overline{W}\subset U$.
Since $\{V_n\}$ is a local base for the topology of X, and $V_0$ is a bounded member, there exists $N>0$ s.t. $V_0\subset 2^n \Lambda^{-1}(W)$ as n>N, i.e. $V_n\subset \Lambda^{-1}(W)$, which leads to $\overline{\Lambda(V_n)}\subset \overline{W}\subset U$.
Since $y_n\in \overline{\Lambda(V_n)}$, then $y_n\in U$. This tell us for any neighborhood U of 0 in Y, there exists a $N>0$ s.t. $y_n \in U$ for all n>N, i.e. $y_n\rightarrow 0$.

2. Actually, I think the phrase "Assume $n\ge 1$ and $y_n$ has been chosen in $\overline{\Lambda(V_n)}$" is somehow misleading, because $y_n$ is not fixed beforehand but rely on the choosing of $x_n$, and the choosing of $x_n$ make the sequence $\{y_n\}$ convergent more strictly to 0.
   In other words,for the construction of $\{x_n\}$, the sequence $\{y_n\}$ can not be chosen beforehand.
3. I make some modification to the original proof in book.I think it would be easier to be understand.

For $\forall y_1\in \overline{\Lambda(V_1)}$, since there is a neighborhood of 0 in Y, here denote as $W_1\subset \overline{\Lambda(V_2)}$ from the proof of 1st part in book, so we have $y_1-W_1\subset y_1-\overline{\Lambda(V_2)}$. Since $y_1\in \overline{\Lambda(V_1)}$, then for any U,neighborhood of 0 in Y, $U\cap W_1$ is a nonempty neighborhood of 0, and $(y_1-U\cap W_1)\cap \Lambda(V_1)\neq \emptyset$. Then we have $x_1\in V_1$ s.t. $\Lambda(x_1)\in y_1-U\cap W_1\subset y_1-W_1\subset y_1-\overline{\Lambda(V_2)}$.Let $y_2=y_1-\Lambda(x_1)$, then $y_2\in U\cap W_1\subset W_1\subset \overline{\Lambda(V_2)}$.

Since for every $\overline{\Lambda(V_{n+1})}$ there is an neighborhood of 0 in Y, here denote as  $W_n$ s.t. $W_n\subset \overline{\Lambda(V_{n+1})}$, with the same derivation, we have $x_n\in V_n$, s.t. $\Lambda(x_n)\in y_n-U\cap W_n\subset y_n-W_n\subset y_n-\overline{\Lambda(V_{n+1})}$, and define $y_{n+1}=y_n-\Lambda(x_n)\in U\cap W_n\subset W_n\subset\overline{\Lambda(V_{n+1})}$.
This leads to $y_{n+1}=y_1-\Sigma_{i=1}^n{\Lambda(x_i)} =y_1-\Lambda(\Sigma_{i=1}^n {x_i})$. Since $\Sigma_{i=1}^n{x_i}$  is convergent and $\Lambda$ is continuous, we denote $x=\Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty} {x_i}$, and $\lim_n{y_{n+1}}=y_1-\Lambda(x)$. But $\{y_i\}_{i\ge 2}\subset U$ and from the arbitrarily choose of U, we have $y_1=\Lambda(x)\in \Lambda(V_0)\subset \Lambda(V)$.